# Динамическое обращение к таблице из VIEW

Tags: функции, sql-server, exec, view

Необходимо создать VIEW к последней загруженной таблице, результат из запроса из 3 строк:

> ```
> declare @last_table varchar (14);
> select TOP 1 @last_table = TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES order by (длинный параметр) desc;
> exec ('select * from '+@last_table);
> ```

Однако в VIEW нельзя использовать ни declare,  ни exec, выход - использовать запрос к функции, в которой будет всё это. Но функции тоже не могут получать значения из Exec, казалось бы `insert into #temptable exec процедура` должна это исправить, но опять же Exec невозможно использовать в функции.

Вопрос: есть ли функция вида `всятаблица('имя таблицы')` или как выполнить exec из функции в минимум строк кода?

Comment: В хэлпе вроде явно написано.

Comment: Нет, в хэлпе (если вы про MSDN) написанно конструкция и то, что нельзя выполнять процедуру в View.
Что нельзя делать, я находил, вопрос именно, как можно сделать так, чтобы было красиво?

Comment: Если вы почитаете мсдн внимательно, то увидите, что представление очень похоже на таблицу и имеет список полей. Более того, список полей фиксирован и не меняется при изменении структуры используемой таблицы - добавление поля в таблице не влияет на представление вида select * from таблица.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае лучше делать exec (' alter view... ') из ddl-триггера и потом обращаться к измененному представлению.